# Why doesn't console.log work in Typescript for me?

Tags: typescript

My code is trivial:

console.log("Hello world");

But when I run:

tsc hello.ts

I don't get any console output.

Is there something additional I need to do?

Comment: `tsc` just compiles your Typescript to JavaScript. To run the generated output, use `node hello.js`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install `ts-node` and use that to run your Typescript files

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

[image]